# Jquery does not update values directly in the first click, only on the socond

Tags: php, jquery

I made a subscribe button, Where users click subscribe and get the total number of subscribers. Example, there is 10 subscribers, when the user clicks subscribe. The value will be updated to 11. Somehow it doesnt work.

```
$subs_no = '10';
<div id='subs_no'>$subs_no</div> <a href='#' id='sub'>Subscribe</a>
```

On the js file:

```
$('#sub').click(
    function () {
        $.post('sub.php', {
            sub: 1
        }, function (sub) {
            $('#subs_no').text(sub);
        });
    });
```

On the php sub.php:

```
$sub = $_POST['sub'];
$con->query("UPDATE sub SET sub=sub + $sub");
$q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sub");
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    $subs = $r['sub'];
    echo $subs;
}
```

After clicking subscribe the button turns into unsubscribe, but the value is still 10 subs. When i click again the button turn into subscribe but the value is 11. It messd my system up.

Comment: What do you have in database? pls show your table structure and its data. And your code does not show function that turn the button into unsubscribe and subscribe.

Comment: Actually the unsubscribe is just another post in another function. That changes the button each click.
the table is sub, only id and sub
the sub is the number of subs.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with following database, it works:

sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub` (
  `sub` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);

INSERT INTO `sub` (`sub`) VALUES (0);
```

html/php:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sub').click(
        function () {
            $.post('sub.php', {
                sub: 1
            }, function (sub) {
                $('#subs_no').text(sub);
            });
        });


    });

    </script>

<div id='subs_no'><?php $subs_no; ?></div>
<a href='#' id='sub'>Subscribe</a>
```

php:

```
<?php

$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'table');

$sub = $_POST['sub'];

$con->query("UPDATE sub SET sub=sub+$sub");
$q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM sub");
while($r = $q->fetch_assoc()){
    $subs = $r['sub'];
    echo $subs;
}

?>
```

If you have id in your table, you would need to supply id when updating and selecting.

Comment: Can u put a where clause, Like where username is = john and add a checker. Like if john has already subbed then it will delete the last sub. So that he can unsub. But if he didnt sub yet, then the data will be inserted. Still not working on mine, it gets update lately. Try it on urs if it will work or not. There is already an id on the sub table, and its on auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. I made a function to update the value of subs after 2 seconds. Because maybe it is caused that the subs are getting updated even though the value of a sub wasnt inserted. Thanms for those who helped though.